# Java JPA: Performant check if Entity is already in DB

Tags: java, jpa, entity

What is the best way / best practice to check if an entity is already in a database using JPA?

I am writing a client that adds hostinformation to a db. For example the attached storage luns, hba etc...

If I want to add a Lun for a host, I have to check if the lun is already in the database. (The Lun can be attached to another host already).

I see 2 possibilites:

1. I make a select for the Lun, to check if it is already in the db
2. Try to insert the Lun and check for an exception (unique constraint)

Does someone have experience with that.

BR, Rene

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
entityManager.find(SomeEntity.class, id)
```

> Returns:
>       the found entity instance or null if the entity does not exist

This will do a simple select in the DB. Just make sure your collections (if any) are lazy.

Comment: It should be ok for a transactional UI client (best practice). For better performances in bulk mode, it will be faster to try the creation and catch the (rare) "already exists exception". (in fact it depends on the probability of existence of the entity, if there are many exceptions, it will be faster to test existence of the entity).

Comment: What do I do, if I don't know the ID?

Comment: then create an JPQL query for other fields.

Comment: If the LUN has some unique information, that should probably be the ID. Then you would know the ID.

Comment: Yes, I changed the  Model now. I use the WWID as ID. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I think checking for the unique constraint exception is a better way. Think about the cost for every insert...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I did. Just persist the entity and deal with the exception in an appropriate manner so that in the end the user can be informed which field(s) are invalid.